# エラーでもない文が強調表示される

Tags: netbeans

netbeans８．１でエラーでもない文が強調表示されます。
コンパイルすると普通に実行できます。
どうしたらいいですか
ウブンツ１５．１０

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 無視してもよさそうですがどうなってほしいですか？出来れば質問に追記してみてください。そうすると欲しい回答が付きやすくなりますよ。

Comment: IDEがヘッダファイルを見付けられていないようですね。警告内容（大抵、マウスオーバー等で表示されると思います）を質問に含めると回答が得られ易いと思います。

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/142617/netbeans-not-able-to-include-files この問題に似ているようですので参考になるかも。

Comment: @take88 どうなって欲しいって、わからないひともいるんだね。経験や知識についてはそのひとの持ち物だからそれには触れないよ。問題はsudo apt-get autoremove このコマンドで治った。いわゆる普通の画面に戻った。

Comment: @mjy リンク確かに問題は似ていたけれど、より深い点では何だ？ライブラリまでのディレクトリの記述を追加したあとに再起動するとそのディレクトリの記述が消えるという問題も一緒にあった実際の回答を全翻訳したわけじゃないから全部が正しいとは言えないけれど。

Answer (score 1):

最近などコンパイラ周辺への変更を行った経験がある場合は

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

たいてい、複数のバージョンが存在します
私は、アセンブラ命令のコンパイルでエラーが出た

それ以外の方はディレクトリの記述を確認してください（ほんとに記述されていないのならコンパイルはできないはずですが。。。）

Answer (score -1):

画像を見た限りinclude文が全角になっているように見えますがどうでしょうか？